# laravel5 user role and permission

Tags: php, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentry

i had laravel4.2 project and now I want to migrate it to laravel5 but,with `cartalyst/sentry": 2.1.*` role and permission not working please give me suggestion what i should do for it.

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*",
        "intervention/image": "2.0.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~1.11",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8",
        "dinesh/easyform": "dev-master",
        "google/recaptcha": "~1.1"      
},
```

Comment: Just curious, are you sure it's laravel 5 and not 5.1? As they are different and could result in other answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert

```
"cartalyst/sentry": "dev-feature/laravel-5"
```

In your json file and do a composer update. It should use the L5 version ( its still in development though. ) or you could use Zizaco's Confide and Entrust packages.

Comment: have you any example of Entrust?

Comment: See their github page. They have examples of how it works.